# Tooltips not being passed through REST API to docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having trouble getting tooltips to be populated in Docusign when making a create envelope request. I am using the REST API and am able to successfully send fairly complex documents. I have a text tab that looks like this

```
{
  "anchorString": "The proposed draw down date is",
  "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
  "anchorUnits": "mms",
  "required": "false",
  "tabLabel": "settlementDrawdownDate",
  "anchorXOffset": "60",
  "anchorYOffset": "-10",
  "fontSize": "Size12",
  "tooltip": "DD/MM/YYYY",
  "validationPattern": "^[0-3][0-9]\/[0-1][0-9]\/2\d{3}$",
  "validationMessage": "Date must in format DD/MM/YYYY"
}
```

When I look at the envelope as it is in the Docusign portal the tooltip field is not populated, and it certainly isn't there in the actual signing screens. I have also attempted to add a tooltip to a number tab with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, instead of "tooltip" use "name":

```
{
  "anchorString": "The proposed draw down date is",
  "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
  "anchorUnits": "mms",
  "required": "false",
  "tabLabel": "settlementDrawdownDate",
  "anchorXOffset": "60",
  "anchorYOffset": "-10",
  "fontSize": "Size12",
  "name": "DD/MM/YYYY",
  "validationPattern": "^[0-3][0-9]\/[0-1][0-9]\/2\d{3}$",
  "validationMessage": "Date must in format DD/MM/YYYY"
}
```

Comment: Looks like this worked, thank you! Is this just a result of outdated documentation or what? It's still called Tooltip when looking in the UI

Comment: Works like a charm!